# Permission error during installation of Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, permissions

During setup I get several errors like the one bellow and none of the service for SQL server get installed. I did quick google search but it seems like the only solution for resolving this issue is re-installation of the whole system which is not an option. Please if you had this problem and resolved it without any drastic measures, please share it.

TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup

The following error has occurred:

Updating permission setting for folder 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\' failed. The folder permission setting were supposed to be set to 'D:(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;FA;;;CO)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;BU)'.

Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1&EvtType=0xE32A4906%25400x0200CF2B

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd be really curious to see the output of `cacls /s` on those directories (while the installer is sitting at the *Retry* box). Or you could try setting the permissions yourself w/`cacls` just to see what it says. I wonder how setup is doing that. Also, I wonder if the other messages (*The process does not possess the `SeSecurityPrivilege` privilege which is required for this operation.*) are at all related. Apparently `seSecurityPrivilege` = `Manage Auditing and Security Log` in the *Local Security Policy > User Rights Assignment*, if that helps any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm late to the party here, I realize, but I just wandered across this after having the same problem. The comment from @fission led me to the following KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000257

The key information is here:

> This behavior is by design. In addition to adding the user account
>   that is running the setup as a local administrator as documented in
>   [How to: Install SQL Server 2008 (Setup)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx), the setup user account
>   requires the following default user rights for the setup to complete
>   successfully.
>
> **Local Policy Object Display Name (*User Right*)**
>
> - Backup files and directories (*SeBackupPrivilege*)
> - Debug Programs (*SeDebugPrivilege*)
> - Manage auditing and security log (*SeSecurityPrivilege*)

Answer (score 4):

This post on MSDN forums worked for me:

I posted something on the Avast forums and got back a response that explains/solves the issue.  Avast has a self-defense module that locks down permissions on the C:\Windows\Temp folder.  It may lock down other folders, but I don't know that for sure.

This can be disabled.  Doing so allows the installation to complete without error.  To disable the Avast self-defence module:

Systray -> Right Click Avast -> Open Avast user interface -> Settings -> Troubleshooting -> Enable self-defense module.

Symantec does not cause the SQL installation to fail like Avast does. And, this problem does not happen on Windows 7.